# Non-desirable auto-scrolling to the beginning of the form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel, autoscroll

I have a Form which contains one control: Panel, which is much bigger than form itself. So, the form's scrollbar is used to navigate this panel. `Autoscroll` property of the form is set to `true`. The problem is: after showing any dialog window the `AutoscrollPosition` is set to begining. How I can override this behavior to save scroll position.

Comment: why are u using the forms autoscroll why not use the panel's autoscroll

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro Because the form can be resized and two scrolls will appear, which is not desired.

Comment: ok its winforms... u didn't mentioned that before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override this by manually setting the scroll pos in your code. Just use Activated and Deactivated events of the form.

Look here for the answer to same problem and the **Code**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020938/why-does-scrolling-position-change-after-refocusing-the-form/2022561#2022561

Comment: Thank you for the respond and useful link. But, strangely, the events Activated and Deactivated are triggered only when I choose another window in my MDI application. But showing dialogs doesn't trigger those events. I verified it by the next code: Deactivate += (s, e) => {                
                MessageBox.Show("Deactivated");
            };
            Activated += (s, e) =>
            {                
                MessageBox.Show("Activated");
            };

Comment: you can't do it that way as the way you are testing it is by putting above code in the form itself and that way you only get Deactivate Event never the Activate event as MessageBox steals the Focus(That proves Message box cause deactivate event) and thus Deactivating the form. To properly test it test it by a button click event showing the message box

Comment: @Micha i just checked it and Opening a Dialog box(i tried OpenFileDialog) makes the Form Deactivated. so code in my answer's link should work.

Comment: T@Shekhar_Pro The idea with MessageBoxes wan't good:) Thank you that pointed it out. But, the events are still not fired - I put breakpoints there. I think my problem related to the fact that I am using MDI: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/b219d183-4f8b-436c-936b-9a2288f4a01b